# create custom link_to button, and getting wrong routing error ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have 2 link_to button, one is to update item record the other one is to archive the item record by updating the active field to false,update button work perfect but im getting error with  Archive link_to button.Im getting this error with

```
No route matches [POST] "/items/10/listing"
```

here is items_controller.rb method

```
  def archive
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.active = false

    if @item.update
       flash[:notice] = "Item been archived..."
    else
    flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
    end
   redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end
```

here the routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :items, except: [:edit] do
   member do
   get 'listing'
   get 'pricing'
   get 'description'
   get 'photo_upload'
   get 'location'
   get 'preload'
   get 'preview'
   end
  resources :photos, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :reservations, only: [:create]
  resources :calendars
  end
end
```

here is the rake routes
[image]

here is index.html.rb

```
<div class="panel-body">
 <% @items.each do |item| %>
   <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #dddbda;padding:0.8rem;display: contents;">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <%= image_tag item.cover_photo(:thumb) %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
    <h4><%= item.item_name %></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right">
    <div>
    <%= link_to "Update", listing_item_path(item), class: "btn btn-form" %>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 1rem;">
   <%= link_to "Archive", listing_item_path(item), method: :archive, class: 'btn-delete' , :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}%>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <hr/>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would change your `routes.rb` to something more like:

```
resources :items, except: [:edit] do
  member do
    get  :listing
    get  :pricing
    get  :description
    get  :photo_upload
    get  :location
    get  :preload
    get  :preview
    post :archive
  end
  resources :photos, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :reservations, only: [:create]
  resources :calendars
end
```

This will give you (amongst other things):

```
       listing_item GET    /items/:id/listing(.:format)                       items#listing
       pricing_item GET    /items/:id/pricing(.:format)                       items#pricing
   description_item GET    /items/:id/description(.:format)                   items#description
  photo_upload_item GET    /items/:id/photo_upload(.:format)                  items#photo_upload
      location_item GET    /items/:id/location(.:format)                      items#location
       preload_item GET    /items/:id/preload(.:format)                       items#preload
       preview_item GET    /items/:id/preview(.:format)                       items#preview
       archive_item POST   /items/:id/archive(.:format)                       items#archive
        item_photos POST   /items/:item_id/photos(.:format)                   photos#create
         item_photo DELETE /items/:item_id/photos/:id(.:format)               photos#destroy
  item_reservations POST   /items/:item_id/reservations(.:format)             reservations#create
     item_calendars GET    /items/:item_id/calendars(.:format)                calendars#index
                    POST   /items/:item_id/calendars(.:format)                calendars#create
  new_item_calendar GET    /items/:item_id/calendars/new(.:format)            calendars#new
 edit_item_calendar GET    /items/:item_id/calendars/:id/edit(.:format)       calendars#edit
      item_calendar GET    /items/:item_id/calendars/:id(.:format)            calendars#show
                    PATCH  /items/:item_id/calendars/:id(.:format)            calendars#update
                    PUT    /items/:item_id/calendars/:id(.:format)            calendars#update
                    DELETE /items/:item_id/calendars/:id(.:format)            calendars#destroy
              items GET    /items(.:format)                                   items#index
                    POST   /items(.:format)                                   items#create
           new_item GET    /items/new(.:format)                               items#new
               item GET    /items/:id(.:format)                               items#show
                    PATCH  /items/:id(.:format)                               items#update
                    PUT    /items/:id(.:format)                               items#update
                    DELETE /items/:id(.:format)                               items#destroy
```

Then change:

```
<%= link_to "Archive", listing_item_path(item), method: :archive, class: 'btn-delete' , :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}%>
```

To:

```
<%= link_to "Archive", archive_item_path(item), method: :post, class: 'btn-delete' , :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}%>
```

You'll notice in the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) (under "Options") that the `method` is a symbol of an HTTP verb and can be `:post`, `:delete`, `:patch`, or `:put`. But NOT `:archive`. That's not an HTTP verb.